# InsertItem into data source in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

So i am doing a small web site in ASP.NET and i need to insert some data into a DB. So far i have this, and it isnt any different from what i've seen in the internet:

```
<h1> Criar Novo Doente </h1>

     <asp:SqlDataSource 
                ID="insertDoente"
                runat ="server"
                ConnectionString ="<%$ ConnectionStrings:principal %>"
                ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient"
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Doentes (do_Nome,do_Sexo,do_DataNascimento,do_IsInternado) VALUES (@do_Nome,@do_Sexo,@do_DataNascimento,0)" >


             <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="do_Nome" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="do_Sexo" Type="String" />
                 <asp:Parameter Name="do_DataNascimento" Type="DateTime" />
            </InsertParameters>

         </asp:SqlDataSource>

     <asp:FormView ID="criarDoente" DefaultMode ="Insert" runat ="server"
                   DataSourceID="insertDoente"
                   DataKeyNames="do_Id"
                   OnItemInserted="MensagemFormView_ItemInserted">


         <InsertItemTemplate>

             <ul>
                 <li>  </li>

             </ul>

             <label>Nome: </label> <asp:TextBox ID="nome" runat ="server" MaxLength="100" TextMode="SingleLine" Text='<%# Bind("do_Nome") %>' />
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NomeRequiredFieldValidator" ErrorMessage="Tem de indicar o nome!"
                ControlToValidate="nome" Display="Dynamic"  runat="server" />
             <br/>
             <label>Sexo </label> <asp:RadioButtonList id="Sexo" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("do_Sexo") %>'><asp:ListItem id="Masc" Text ="Masculino" Value = "Masculino"></asp:ListItem> <asp:ListItem id="fem" Text ="Feminino" Value ="Feminino"></asp:ListItem> </asp:RadioButtonList>
             <br/>
             <label>Data de Nascimento: </label> <asp:TextBox ID="dataNasc" runat ="server" MaxLength="100" TextMode="SingleLine" Text='<%# Bind("data") %>' />
             <asp:CompareValidator id="dataCompare" ControlToValidate="dataNasc"
                Display="Dynamic" Operator="DataTypeCheck"
                Type="Date"
                ErrorMessage="A data tem de estar no formato YYYY/MM/DD"
                ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />

             <br />

             <asp:Button ID="Criar" runat="server" Text="Criar" CommandName="Insert" />






         </InsertItemTemplate>


         </asp:FormView>
```

When i press the button to create, it triggers the onItemInserted event but nothing is added to the database :S Am i doing something wrong ?

EDIT: The fields of the insert commands are ordered the same way they are in the DB, only the ID is missing but that isnt needed or is it?

Comment: You mean: it doesn't insert, or does it insert empty rows? I don't see how the fields are filled now. Are you sure you don't need a `FormParameter` for example?

Comment: They dont insert, i checked the DB and its empty. Let me check on those form parameters.

Comment: i tried with form parameters and still nothing.

Comment: i solved it :) it was my DataBase that didnt have the identity set to the primary key.

Comment: Please self-answer your question if useful for others or delete it.